# Symfony2: Handling form submissions

Tags: symfony

This is my first time trying to handle a form, and I'm following the official [documentation for Symfony 2.3](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). Displaying the form has worked out, but I have not been able to handle it.

I get the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata::addPropertyConstraint()
>   must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint, array
>   given, called in
>   /home/torob/lampstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/htdocs/A/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php
>   on line 90 and defined in
>   /home/torob/lampstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/htdocs/A/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php
>   line 193
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Here is my controller:

```
public function newIdeaPostAction(Request $request){
    $idea = new Idea();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($idea)
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('shortDescription', 'text')
        ->add('valueDescription', 'text')
        ->add('description', 'textarea')
        ->add('Next', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ideside_idea_success'));
    }
}
```

I know that it's the method-call `$form->handleRequest($request)` that creates the error. I also tried to do it "the old way" from the 2.1-documentation (they say that the handleRequest-method is new):

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
    }
}
```

This gave me the same error.

**Extra info:**

Here is the route:

```
ideside_newidea_post:
  path: /post/idea
  defaults:  { _controller: IdesideIdeaBundle:Default:newIdeaPost }
  methods:  [POST]
```

Here is the stacktrace (...nameofproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php):

```
 *
 * @return ClassMetadata This object
 */
public function addPropertyConstraint($property, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (!isset($this->properties[$property])) {
        $this->properties[$property] = new PropertyMetadata($this->getClassName(), $property);
```

Here is my validation.yml (although I don't know if it's relevant, since the error occurs before the isValid-function is called in my controller):

```
Ideside\IdeaBundle\Entity\Idea:
    properties:
        title:
            - NotBlank: {message: "blabla"}
        shortDescription:
            - NotBlank: {message: "blabla"}
            - Length: {max: 115, maxMessage: "blabla", min: 6, minMessage: "blabla"}
        valueDescription:
            -Length: {max: 115, maxMessage: "blabla", min: 5, minMessage: "blabla"}
        description:
            - Length: {max: 5000, maxMessage: "blabla"}
```

Sorry to have bothered you guys if this turns out to be some kind of noobish mistake. 
**If any of you could help me out with this you would be doing me a *great* favour** (and potentially also the world if our project works out as intended).

Comment: `bind()` is called `submit()` since Symfony 2.2 I think

Comment: Thank you for the hint byf-ferdy!

Comment: I tried to replace $form->bind($request) with $form->submit($request) when retrying the old way of doing things, but I still got the same error. (By the way, if you find it interesting: It seems they still use bind() in the 2.2-documentation, but when typing bind() in Php-storm now I'm told it's depreciated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, this one took me awhile to figure out...  You're just missing the space between the dash and the "L" in your valueDescription length attribute.

```
Ideside\IdeaBundle\Entity\Idea:
    properties:
        title:
            - NotBlank: {message: "blabla"}
        shortDescription:
            - NotBlank: {message: "blabla"}
            - Length: {max: 115, maxMessage: "blabla", min: 6, minMessage: "blabla"}
        valueDescription:
            // This is the original line
            // You do not have a space between the dash and Length
            // -Length: {max: 115, maxMessage: "blabla", min: 5, minMessage: "blabla"}
            // It should be this
            - Length: {max: 115, maxMessage: "blabla", min: 5, minMessage: "blabla"}
        description:
            - Length: {max: 5000, maxMessage: "blabla"}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! That solved the problem. Well, I'll certainly never make that mistake that again. Dunno what I would have done without the help of nice people like you. If you're ever in Trondheim and want a beer, let me know.

Comment: I was getting this same error and couldn't figure it out. A similar solution worked for me. I was missing the indentation for the groups property in the yaml file.